# Gravity and Collision - Simple VB Game

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a game sorta like iCopter where there you control an object and guide it through moving obstacles.

So I made a simple png in Fireworks where it's just mountains and I wanted to add it to VB so that if the object touches a part of the PNG (Not the Picturebox because that would defeat the purpose) it would end the game.

Therefore the main problem is how to make VB Recognize the PNG without a picturebox (if that's even possible) ...

Thanks

[image: ScreenShot]

I have motion of the background continously left, and I can move the car, however I want to create collision and that will be difficult seing as it would be with the bigger picturebox, not the actual image inside...

---

New Code/Work

```
Public Class Form1
Dim upc, leftc, rightc, downc As Boolean
Dim speedofblocks As Integer = 5
Dim speedofguy As Integer = 6
Dim standing As Boolean
Dim blocks(1) As PictureBox
Dim floor(1) As PictureBox


    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then

        leftc = True
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.guy1
    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        rightc = True
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.guy1
    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        upc = True
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.guy1
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        downc = True
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.guy1
    End If






    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then

        leftc = False


    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        rightc = False
    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        upc = False
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        downc = False
    End If
End Sub

    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.GUystand
    blocks(1) = PictureBox1
    blocks(1) = PictureBox2
    blocks(1) = PictureBox3
    blocks(1) = PictureBox4
    blocks(1) = PictureBox5
    blocks(1) = PictureBox6
    blocks(1) = PictureBox7
    blocks(1) = PictureBox8
    blocks(1) = PictureBox3
    blocks(1) = PictureBox10
    blocks(1) = PictureBox11
    blocks(1) = PictureBox12
    blocks(1) = PictureBox13
    blocks(1) = PictureBox14
    blocks(1) = PictureBox15
    blocks(1) = PictureBox16
    blocks(1) = PictureBox17
    blocks(1) = PictureBox18
    blocks(1) = PictureBox19
    blocks(1) = PictureBox20
    blocks(1) = PictureBox21
    blocks(1) = PictureBox22
    blocks(1) = PictureBox23
    blocks(1) = PictureBox24
    blocks(1) = PictureBox25
    blocks(1) = PictureBox26
    blocks(1) = PictureBox27
    blocks(1) = PictureBox28
    blocks(1) = PictureBox29
    blocks(1) = PictureBox30
    blocks(1) = PictureBox31
    blocks(1) = PictureBox32
    blocks(1) = PictureBox33
    blocks(1) = PictureBox34
    blocks(1) = PictureBox35
    blocks(1) = PictureBox36
    blocks(1) = PictureBox37
    blocks(1) = PictureBox38
    blocks(1) = PictureBox39
    blocks(1) = PictureBox40
    blocks(1) = PictureBox41
    blocks(1) = PictureBox42
    blocks(1) = PictureBox43
    blocks(1) = PictureBox44
    blocks(1) = PictureBox45
    blocks(1) = PictureBox46
    blocks(1) = PictureBox47
    blocks(1) = PictureBox48
    blocks(1) = PictureBox49

    floor(1) = picturebox50


End Sub




    If leftc = True Then
        PictureBox1.Left -= speedofguy
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.guy1
    End If
    If rightc = True Then
        PictureBox1.Left += speedofguy
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.guy1
    End If
    If upc = True Then
        PictureBox1.Top -= speedofguy
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.guy1
    End If

    If downc = True Then
        PictureBox1.Top += speedofguy
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.guy1
    End If



Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox2.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox3.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox4.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox5.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox6.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox7.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox8.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox9.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox10.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox11.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox12.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox13.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox14.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox15.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox16.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox17.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox18.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox19.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox20.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox21.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox22.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox23.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox24.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox25.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox26.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox27.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox28.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox29.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox30.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox31.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox32.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox33.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox34.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox35.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox36.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox37.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox38.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox39.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox40.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox41.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox42.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox43.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox44.Left -= speedofblocks

    PictureBox45.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox46.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox47.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox48.Left -= speedofblocks
    PictureBox49.Left -= speedofblocks




End Sub

Private Sub Gravity_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Gravity.Tick
    PictureBox1.Top += 3

    For x As Integer = 1 To 49

        If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(floor(x).Bounds) And floor(x).Visible = True Then
            standing = True
            PictureBox1.Top -= 3
        End If

        If PictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(blocks(x).Bounds) And blocks(x).Visible = True Then
            standing = True
            PictureBox1.Top -= 3
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure I messed up the arrays, and the Bounds.Intersectswith.. etc. Basically trying to get some basic collision and gravity. I made a bunch of picture boxes that are all black blocks that scroll left and then I want the player to jump over them.

Comment: WinForms will not be good at this.  Try looking at XNA for game development on windows.

Comment: While I did simple games in windows forms myself with visual basic (and lots of buttons) when I was a kid, I would not recommend doing so. Just dig through a XNA tutorial. It's quite easy to grasp and your effort will pay of quickly.

Comment: Yup I know that XNA is much better, this is for a project so I'm just using VB to do something simple ... I editted the code with some new stuff..

Answer (score 2):

As others will say, Winforms is not the best for games, its optimized more for data entry stuff and static windows. That being said, a PictureBox control is just a control that draws an image to the screen. What you would want to do is override the default rendering of your control/form so you can do all the drawing yourself. See below link for a start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6.aspx